# Specman(e) Questions

Tags: specman

I want to emit an event only at the first rising edge of clock.

for example

```
event clkr_e is rise ('pll_clk') @ sim;
```

`clkr_e` is emitted at every rising clock.

But I need to emit an event only at first rising edge of pll_clk. Could any one please shed some light on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag:

```
clk_has_risen : bool;
keep clk_has_risen == FALSE;

event first_clk_rise_e is true(clk_has_risen == FALSE) @ clkr_e;
on first_clk_rise_e {
    clk_has_risen = TRUE;
};
```

Also, this is a performance no-no:

```
event clkr_e is rise ('pll_clk') @ sim;
```

You should use the Specman `simple_port` construct.  We doubled the speed of our simulations when we switched to ports instead of tick-accesses.  Look it up in your Specman docs.